# Trying to get board details from trello

Tags: angularjs, trello

hi i am new to this but i want to get card details from trello as object i an using angular to fetch data 
but all i am getting is invalid key

code

```
app.controller("TrelloController", function($http,$scope){

    $http({method: 'GET', url:'https://api.trello.com/1/cards/4eea503d91e31d174600008f?fields=name,idList&member_fields=fullName&key=[0a45465a69bdbf89d7b0c64e77257665]&token=[genrated using trello]'})
    .then(
        function(data,response) {

            console.log('result: ', data);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log('An error occured');
        }
    );


 });
```

Comment: URL for trello board details is: "https://api.trello.com/1/members/me/boards?filter=open&fields=name&key=" + appKey + "&token=";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the documentation says:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/cards/4eea503d91e31d174600008f?fields=name,idList&member_fields=fullName&key=[application_key]&token=[optional_auth_token]
```

`[application_key]` and `[optional_auth_token]` are just placeholders.

Remove these brackets `[]` and you should be fine.